boto3 config error with MLflow but not with direct Python
I am struggling with the following issue.
I setup a MLflow server on an EC2 instance, with permission to read and write on S3.
I check that everything works fine doing the following in Python:
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.list_buckets()
file_content = "This is a test file."
file_name = 'test-file.txt'
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
s3.put_object(
         Bucket=bucket_name, 
         Key=file_name, 
         Body=file_content)

The code does write the file to S3.
But when trying to use the MLflow server from a remote client, by setting:
train_server = f"http://{public_ip}:{mlflow_port}"
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(train_server)

the mlflow_logartifact in the following code does not work:
with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    mlflow.log_param("param1", 5)
    mlflow.log_artifact("local_artifact.txt")

I get error:
    mlflow.log_artifact("local_artifact.txt")
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py", line 1109, in log_artifact
    MlflowClient().log_artifact(run_id, local_path, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py", line 1914, in log_artifact
    self._tracking_client.log_artifact(run_id, local_path, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py", line 812, in log_artifact
    artifact_repo.log_artifact(local_path, artifact_path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 177, in log_artifact
    s3_client=self._get_s3_client(), local_file=local_file, bucket=bucket, key=dest_path
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 135, in _get_s3_client
    return _get_s3_client(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 110, in _get_s3_client
    return _cached_get_s3_client(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/s3_artifact_repo.py", line 69, in _cached_get_s3_client
    return boto3.client(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 80, in _get_default_session
    setup_default_session()
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 34, in setup_default_session
    DEFAULT_SESSION = Session(**kwargs)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._setup_loader()
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 129, in _setup_loader
    self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 802, in get_component
    return self._components.get_component(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 1140, in get_component
    self._components[name] = factory()
                             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 199, in <lambda>
    lambda: create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')),
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 323, in get_config_variable
    return self.get_component('config_store').get_config_variable(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 472, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 678, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/configprovider.py", line 765, in provide
    scoped_config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/mlxp-wrapper/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 422, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile () could not be found

I've spent the whole week-end wrapping my head on the source of the error but can't find any. I tried deleting or creating aws config files, checked environment variables on remote host, etc. but nothing worked.
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried a simplified version of the initial problem, as well as manipulating config variables on remote EC2 instance.

Found the issue for those who might face the same problem. boto3 can have correct credentials through the ~/.aws/credentials file (in which I provided credentials of a role dedicated to S3 access), but MLflow needs the environment variable AWS_PROFILE to be set to said profile. I found no way to force specific boto3 session credentials use by MLflow without using the environment variable.
